# Flex property not being applied on TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native

I'm following [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/a-definitive-react-native-guide-for-react-developers-part-3/#inthethirdarticlehewrotelettherebegameandtherewasagame) tutorial and got stuck with the dynamic `TouchableOpacity` elements. For some reason, the flex property is not being applied. When I view the elements using chrome's dev tools I can see them but they don't have a flex property. If I add it manually, I get the look I want.

Here is the `render` snippet:

```
render() {
        const { rgb, size } = this.state;
        const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header fontSize={40} />
                <View
                    style={{
                        height: width * 0.875,
                        width: width * 0.8758,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                    }}
                >
                    {Array(size)
                        .fill()
                        .map((val, columnIndex) => (
                            <View
                                style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: 'column' }}
                                key={columnIndex}
                            >
                                {Array(size)
                                    .fill()
                                    .map((val, rowIndex) => (
                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                            key={`${rowIndex}.${columnIndex}`}
                                            style={{
                                                flex: 1,
                                                backgroundColor: `rgb(${rgb.r}, ${rgb.g}, ${rgb.b})`,
                                                margin: 2,
                                            }}
                                            onPress={() =>
                                                console.log(
                                                    rowIndex,
                                                    columnIndex
                                                )
                                            }
                                        />
                                    ))}
                            </View>
                        ))}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Stupid mistake. Was importing `TouchableOpacity` from the wrong package. Check that you import from `react-native`

Comment: Wow, same here! Thanks for posting this question and answer. VS Code's autoimport makes this too easy to do.